# Problema com menu switch case e while

Tags: java, while, switch

Meu objetivo é que após eu executar uma das opções do menu e dizer que não quero continuar nela, eu possa inserir outra opção (ou a mesma caso queira voltar).

Meu código executa a primeira opção que eu digito porém não capta a segunda, apenas continua a rodar o código. Ex: se eu colocar que quero lançar, e depois digo que não quero mais lançar notas de outro aluno, ele me faz a pergunta do que desejo fazer porém independente da minha resposta ele executa o segundo caso "notas". Segue o código:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entrega {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nomes [] = new String[100];
        double notas [][] = new double [100][5];
        String resposta = "S";
        double media = 0;
        double soma = 0;
        int qtdnomes = 0;
        String turma = "";
        String resposta1 = "s";
        String resposta2 = "s";
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("O que deseja fazer? LANCAR notas, ver NOTAS, ver RESULTADOS, SAIR?" );       
        String opcao = input.nextLine();
        while (resposta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            switch (opcao) {
            case "lancar":
                while(resposta1.equalsIgnoreCase("S")){
                    for(int i=0;i<=nomes.length;i++) {
                        input = new Scanner (System.in);
                        System.out.println("Qual o nome da turma?");
                        turma = input.nextLine();
                        input = new Scanner (System.in);
                        System.out.println("Qual o nome do aluno?");
                        nomes[i] = input.nextLine();
                        qtdnomes=qtdnomes+1;
                        for(int j=0;j<=3;j++) {
                            System.out.println("Qual a nota "+j);
                            notas[i][j]=input.nextDouble();
                            soma=soma+notas[i][j];
                            media=soma/4;
                            notas[i][4] = media;
                        }
                        System.out.println("Deseja lançar notas de outro aluno? S/N?");
                        resposta1 = input.next();
                        media=0;
                        soma=0;
                        input=null;
                        if(resposta1.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                            resposta="n";
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    try{
                        File medias = new File(turma);
                        FileWriter gravador = new FileWriter(medias,true);
                        for(int p=0;p<qtdnomes;p++){
                            gravador.write(nomes[p]+System.lineSeparator());
                            gravador.write(Arrays.toString(notas[p])+System.lineSeparator());
                            gravador.flush();
                        }
                    }   


                    catch(IOException e){
                        System.err.printf("Erro na gravação do arquivo: %s.\n",e.getMessage());
                    }

                    input = new Scanner (System.in);
                    System.out.println("O que deseja fazer? LANCAR notas, ver NOTAS, ver RESULTADOS, SAIR?" );       
                    opcao = input.nextLine();
                }
            case "notas":
                while(resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {
                String nomearquivo="";
                input = new Scanner (System.in);
                System.out.println("Nome do arquivo de texto");
                nomearquivo = input.next();
                try {
                    FileReader arquivo = new FileReader(nomearquivo);
                    BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(arquivo);
                    String linha;
                    while((linha = leitor.readLine())!=null){
                        System.out.println(linha);
                    }
                    input = new Scanner (System.in);
                    System.out.println("Deseja consultar outra turma? S/N?");
                    resposta2=input.nextLine();
                    if (resposta2.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                        break;
                    }

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: antes de receber o valor, chama o nextLine() de novo, parece ser buffer.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 6):

O `switch` tem algo chamado *fallthrough* automático, ou seja, ele não é excludente, ele executará todas as opções se o código deixar. Para mudar este comportamento precisa colocar um `break` no final do `case`, assim ele encerra o `switch` excluindo a execução dos demais.

Esse comportamento é criticado por quase todo mundo, foi um erro do C e todas as linguagens copiam dizendo que é para deixar os programadores mais antigos confortáveis. Mas eles mudam um monte de coisa na linguagem que não deixam nada confortáveis, então é um argumento falho.

Já o `break` usado dentro do `if` quebrará o `switch` e acho que está imaginando
que ele quebrará o `while`. Esse é outro problema, o mesmo comando quebra coisas diferentes.

É possível que tenha outros problemas, o código faz muita coisa junto, é difícil de entender, e já vi algumas coisas que ficariam melhores de outro jeito. Se quebrar isso em métodos ficará melhor, se declarar as variáveis junto do seu uso e não tudo antes ficará melhor, se não capturar exceção para fazer algo inútil ficará melhor. Se tornar o código mais fácil de ler ficará melhor.